# How to remove image photo gradation in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to remove gradation in image.

I used K-means algorithms but I can`t get the result I need.

How can I get just one yellow circle composed of just one color?

[image]

Comment: Does [Bundling RGB values when Posterizing Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17759622/1115360) help?

Comment: The cost function used by Otsu may be helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method

Comment: Can you provide a [example] for "used K-means algorithms", including the input image, so we can reproduce. Also the expected output as image would be better than to interpret words' meaning.

Comment: Convert the image to another colorspace first, e.g. HSV, and cluster only on HS values.

Comment: if you reduce it to few enough colors, it might do what you want. have you tried that?